# How can I organize a table based on similarities of two columns?

Tags: perl, sorting

The following table represents a tab-delimited file that I have.

```
1   2     3   
A   Jack  01
A   Mary  02
A   Jack  03
B   Mary  04
B   Mike  05
B   Mary  06
C   Mike  07
C   Mike  08
C   Jack  09
```

I would like to parse this text file and create multiple text files based on columns 1 & 2. Each text file would contain data (column 3) where column 1&2 are the same. So in this example, the data would be organized as follows:

```
> file1.txt
A   Jack  01
A   Jack  03

> file2.txt
A   Mary  02

> file3.txt
B   Mary  04
B   Mary  06

> file4.txt
B   Mike  05

> file5.txt
C   Mike  07
C   Mike  08

> file6.txt
C   Jack  09

#What would be the best way to tackle this? The only method I can think of is to create a 2-dimensional array and then comparing every row/col pair.
```

edit: The following code seems to work. Is there a better alternative?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "/home/user/Desktop/a.txt";
my @array =();
open(FILE, $file) || die "cannot open file";

while(my $line = <FILE>){
    my @row = split("\t", $line);
    my $two = $row[1]."\t".$row[2];
    push(@array, $two);
}

close FILE;

@array = uniq(@array);

my $counter = 0;

foreach my $x (@array){
    #unique tab
    open(SEC, $file) || die "cannot open 2nd time\n";
    while(my $line = <SEC>){
        if($line =~ /($x)/){
        my $output = "txt".$counter.".txt";
        print "hit!\n";
        open(OUT, '>>', $output) || die "cannot write out";
        print OUT $line."\n";
        close OUT;
       }
    }
    $counter++;
 }

 close SEC;
 sub uniq {
     return keys %{{ map { $_ => 1 } @_ }};
 }
```

I know how to sort it via command line (sort -t: -k1,2 a.txt) but I'm wondering how to do it within perl and writeout the multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the two first fields and use them as hash keys. Each hash key points to an array where you add all relevant lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "/home/johan/Desktop/tabdel.txt"
    or die $!;

<$fh>;  # Skip header

my $data = {};
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    # match the fields
    next unless $line =~ /^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\S+/;

    # append $line to the hash value, key is the concatenated two first fields:
    push @{ $data->{"$1 $2"}->{'lines'} }, "$line";
}

my $file_count = 0;
foreach my $key (sort keys %{$data}) {
    my $qfn = "file".(++$file_count).".txt";
    open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
        or die $!;

    foreach my $line (@{ $data->{$key}->{'lines'} }) {
        print $fh $line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
my $n = 1;

while (<>) {
    next if $. == 1;
    my @a = split;

    if ( !exists $hash{ $a[0] }{ $a[1] } ) {
        open $hash{ $a[0] }{ $a[1] }, '>', 'file' . $n++ . '.txt' or die $!;
    }

    print { $hash{ $a[0] }{ $a[1] } } $_;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile.txt`

Acknowledging [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s point about possibly running out of file handles in case your dataset is large, here's a option that collects results in a hash and then prints the results to files (the usage is the same as the above script):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( %hash, %seen );
my $n = 0;

while (<>) {
    next if $. == 1;
    my ( $key, $elem ) = /(.+\s+)(\d+)\Z/;
    push @{ $hash{$key} }, $elem;
}

for my $key ( sort { $hash{$a}->[0] <=> $hash{$b}->[0] } keys %hash ) {
    $n++ if !$seen{$key}++;
    open my $fh, '>', 'file' . $n . '.txt' or die $!;
    print $fh "$key$_\n" for @{ $hash{$key} };
}
```

Comment: This solution risks running out of file handles as only a limited number can be open at a time. I seem to remember this being as low as 64 on some systems?

Comment: @ikegami - Yes--I noticed that the results weren't in exactly in the same order the OP wanted.

Comment: If the ordering is important (even though he simply said he wanted to "organize" the data), a `sort` would most like take care of that trivially.

Comment: @ikegami - I needed that `sort` nudge--thanks.  For the OP, `C   Mike` is in file5.txt and `C   Jack` is in file6.txt, but I reversed them by defaulting to a lexical `sort` instead of order of appearance.  This is ow fixed.